# Identical textField functions in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have two identical functions in my ViewController and it seems that neither of them can be renamed.

The first one is used to limit characters and show the number left.

```
    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        if let textField = textField as? UITextField {

        if (range.length + range.location > textField.text!.characters.count) {
                return false;
        }

        let newLength = textField.text!.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length;
        cLabel.text =  String(25 - newLength)
        return newLength <= 25 // To just allow up to … characters

        }
    return true;
    }
```

The second one enables a button when text is added to the same textField.

```
    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        // Find out what the text field will be after adding the current edit
        let text = (ahskField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

        if text.isEmpty{//Checking if the input field is not empty
            ahskButton.userInteractionEnabled = false //Enabling the button
            ahskButton.enabled = false
        } else {
            ahskButton.userInteractionEnabled = true //Disabling the button
            ahskButton.enabled = true
        }

        // Return true so the text field will be changed
        return true
    }
```

Is there a way to combine them or anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need one of the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` functions.

Put all of your logic in the one method.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    // Find out what the text field will be after adding the current edit
    let text = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
    let newLength = text.characters.count
    if newLength <= 25 {
        cLabel.text = String(25 - newLength)
        if text.isEmpty { //Checking if the input field is not empty
            ahskButton.userInteractionEnabled = false //Enabling the button
            ahskButton.enabled = false
        } else {
            ahskButton.userInteractionEnabled = true //Disabling the button
            ahskButton.enabled = true
        }

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```